# PHP, disable automatic input[] to array

Tags: php, html, forms, post

If you post a html form with inputs having names ending with [], php will automatically make these $_POST-values into an array.

For example, without brackets:

```
<input name="email" value="a" />

var_dump($_POST["email"])    
//string 'a' (length=1)
```

With brackets:

```
<input name="email[]" value="a" />
<input name="email[]" value="b" />

var_dump($_POST["email"])    
//array
//  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
//  1 => string 'b' (length=1)
```

My problem is that previously i didn't know about this so i've been coding my website with the assumption that $_POST-variables always are of type string. Naturally i perform standard input validation but only assuming that the variables already are strings.

So what if a hacker takes one of my normal inputs, like `<input name="email" .../>` and posts it with the brackets after. Then my code fetching $_POST["email"] would be an array!

I could imagine there are cases where this would be a security problem, for example startsWith-function could work on both strings and arrays. I haven't researched the full implications of it and i don't want to either, i just want to disable the function completely so i can trust all $_POST-variables to always be strings.

Is there any way to disable this function globally or is the only option to find-replace all and add a (string)-cast in front of every access of $_POST?

Comment: Assuming you do type comparison and then do email string validation after. So what do hacker achieve by doing so as you have mentioned? an invalid error message?

Comment: @invisal I didn't do type comparison because i thought the type would always be string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just loop through the POST array, and fix them this way.
But, since you said you don't ever plan to need this, why not just loop through the _POST array, check if anything is a non-string, and then just throw an exception? No need to give the hypothetical hacker a nice fallback or workaround :)

```
foreach($_POST as $val) {
   if (!is_string($val)) {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException('POST arguments should be strings only');
   }
}
```

I find the best way to deal with such issues is to be strict, and throw exceptions for cases where a client (browser/evil guy) is clearly messing around with stuff ;)